# How to reset a jframe and saving text from a jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I want to write a little programm. There is defined number of cycles the programm shall run. The User inserts text in a Jtextfield. Everytime the user hits enter, one cycle is counted and the same JFrame shall be created again. This procedure repeats until the max. number of cycles is reached. The programm shall create another Jframe. I tried to write the code, but the program does not increase the number of cycles.

```
public class oneJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private int Cycles = 0;
    
    
    public oneJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }                    

    private void clsWinBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dispose();
    }                                         

    protected void playerNameFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (Cycles <= 4) {
            System.out.println(Cycles );
            dispose();
            oneJFrame JFrame1 = new oneJFrame();
            JFrame1.setVisible(true);
            Cycles++;
        } else {
            anotherJFrame Jframe2 = new anotherJFrame ();
            Jframe2.setVisible(true);
        }
        
  
    }
```

I think I know the problem that I´ve got: Evertime the If Statement is true and the Jframe is disposed and a new one is created the int Cycles is set to 0. If this is the problem, I have no Idea to solve this. Is there a need to dispose the Jframe or is there a way just to save the text in the textfield and then reload the frame? Or is there something else I could do?

I am using the NetBeans GUI Builder.

Comment: Don't keep creating a new frame. Just refresh the data displayed on the frame for each cycle. Then you can keep in instance variable to track the number of cycles.

Comment: First, what makes you think you need to sprog a new JFrame? What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing that? Second, sprogging a series of new JFrame objects need to be done anonymously, unless you have some known fixed number, in which case each can be named ahead of time and only initialized if necessary. In your case, your second JFrame is always called JFrame2, which means you're not making new JFrames, but rather, replacing them because you keep reusing the same name. Better rethink your approach, because the one you've chosen won't pay off.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1):

This is happend because when you create a new `OneFrame`, new `Cycles` created and automaticly equals to 0.
To fix that, change the variable `Cycles` to `static`, so will be 1 variable to every `OneFrame` you will create, and will not reset to 0 every time you create a new `OneFrame`.
For example, use:

```
private static int Cycles = 0;
```

Instead of:

```
private int Cycles = 0;
```